# Help picking an appropriate citing style

Tags: citations, writing, citation-style

I wrote a paper about governance mechanisms at StackExchange in which I got a lot of informations out of questions (especially on meta). I have kept all my references.

My teacher is letting us pick which style we want to use for the paper as long as we apply it thoroughly. In my other courses, we use APA but if I start writing (StackExchange, 2014) everytime I use an info out of a question, my paper is going to be illegible. From what I've read, you're only supposed to cite things that you've paraphrased, ideas, not necessarily information that you've found or researched but I do want to give credit where it belongs and I would also like if my teacher would be able to retrace where I've found things but APA doesn't seem to include such a thing as a bibliography.

I would like to:

- have a bibliography at the end containing the documents I've consulted for my research
- be able to have my citations as footnotes

Which style should I go for in this case?

Comment: "not necessarily information that you've found or researched" - any information that isn't original and isn't common knowledge _does_ need a citation.

Comment: @ff524 however, if the actual information is in article A, but you found out that A exists only because a fellow researcher X or article B told you "hey, A seems to be relevant to your problem" - then X and B don't deserve any citation, only the actual source A does. X/B might possibly get a mention in 'acknowledgements' part of the article if that was very important.

Comment: @Peteris agreed. However,  SE answers are required to be more than just a "hey, this link seems relevant."  It's likely that the OP uses the interpretation/synthesis of information found there, which should be cited.

Comment: @ff524 If you read a one-paragraph summary of an article; it's intriguing; then you read the whole article and it affects the conclusions of paper - imho you should cite the paper and not cite that summary.

Comment: @Peteris yes, if it's just a summary. Anyways, I thought the OP means he/she only plans to cite ideas/paraphrased content and not information, regardless of whether the info came from SE or from an original source. Perhaps OP can clarify this point.

Comment: Most of the information I'm using is to clarify some mechanisms that I would normally get through interviews (i.e. information that is not available on the blog such as what happens when the community wants to dismiss a moderator, etc.). It could potentially be "common" knowledge if I had been a user of StackExchange for a long time.

Comment: @Emilie "common knowledge" means it is commonly known by the expected audience of your paper... so unless you are writing a paper that will be read primarily by long-time SE users, you should cite that information :)

Comment: _writing (StackExchange, 2014) everytime_ — But why would you? StackExchange is not the name of the author!

Comment: @JeffE I agree with you but I'd need someone to provide me a better option...StackExchange requires to be cited and users can change their name anytime. Also, more often then not, I'm not so much citing a particular idea by a specific person but refering to many informations provided in a Q&A to come up with ties to other readings.

Answer (score 3):

Though I'm not a fan of it in general, in your case the IEEE style could work very well.  In the body of the paper, references are numbered in square brackets, like this: [1] and [2,3].  In the bibliography, you'd just have one entry per web page, with the URL.  If you use LaTex, it's easy to make these all active hyper links, so that your professor can click on the "[1]" to go to the bibliography entry, and then click on the URL to go to the StackExchange web page.  It's also possible to make the references hyperlinked in MS Word, but it might take some manual formatting steps to link each reference to each bibliography entry.

Answer (score 1):

One citation style that may be appropriate could be [The Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html)  which has two documentation systems:

1. notes and bibliography and;
2. author-date

The notes and bibliography system which should suit as per your question is described on the website as such;

> The notes and bibliography style is preferred by many in the humanities, including those in literature, history, and the arts. This style presents bibliographic information in notes and, often, a bibliography. It accommodates a variety of sources, including esoteric ones less appropriate to the author-date system.

As a History student this is the style that I am using for my masters thesis.

The style uses the following example for a website as per your question.

> **Website**
>
> A citation to website content can often be limited to a mention in the text or in a note (“As of July 19, 2008, the McDonald’s Corporation listed on its website . . .”). If a more formal citation is desired, it may be styled as in the examples below. Because such content is subject to change, include an access date or, if available, a date that the site was last modified.
>
> 1. “Google Privacy Policy,” last modified March 11, 2009, http://www.google.com/intl/en/privacypolicy.html.
> 2. “McDonald’s Happy Meal Toy Safety Facts,” McDonald’s Corporation, accessed July 19, 2008, http://www.mcdonalds.com/corp/about/factsheets.html.
> 3. “Google Privacy Policy.”
> 4. “Toy Safety Facts.”
>
> Google. “Google Privacy Policy.” Last modified March 11, 2009.
>   http://www.google.com/intl/en/privacypolicy.html. 
>   McDonald’s Corporation.
>
> “McDonald’s Happy Meal Toy Safety Facts.” Accessed July 19, 2008. http://www.mcdonalds.com/corp/about/factsheets.html.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest APA. It does have citation styles and there are many wonderful automatic generators out there that are up to date and will create the bibliography for you by merely data scraping website URLs and by entering the ISBN# of whatever book you may have used.

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/01/ has a great article

http://www.bibme.org/    is a wonderful generator site I've used numerous times.